# The problem of deriving the formula, the left term of the equation is missing 1/2

Tags: derivation-of-formulae

The derivation in the paper:
$$
V=-\frac{\left( kT/e \right) \left( x+ct \right)}{ct},\ E=\frac{kT/\left( ec \right)}{t}
$$

$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 \varepsilon _0\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2V}{\mathrm{d}x^2}=n_0e\left[ \exp \left( \dfrac{eV}{kT} \right) -1 \right]&\text{for}\,\,x<0\ \ \ \left( Eq.1 \right)\\
 \varepsilon _0\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2V}{\mathrm{d}x^2}=n_0e\exp \left( \dfrac{eV}{kT} \right) &\text{for}\,\,x>0 \ \ \ \left( Eq.2 \right)\\
\end{array} \right. \ 
$$
Integration then gives:
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 \dfrac{1}{2}\varepsilon _0E^2=n_0kT\left[ \exp \left( \dfrac{eV}{kT} \right) -1-\dfrac{eV}{kT} \right] &\text{for}\,\,x<0\ \left( Eq.3 \right)\\
 \dfrac{1}{2}\varepsilon _0E^2=n_0kT\exp \left( \dfrac{eV}{kT} \right) &\text{for}\,\,x>0\ \left( Eq.4 \right)\\
\end{array} \right. \ 
$$
where $E=-\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}x}$. The boundary conditions employed here are $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}x}=0$, $V=0$ at $x=-\infty$ and $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}x}=0$, $V=-\infty$ at $x=+\infty$.

The above content is the introduction and derivation in the paper. My aim is to derive **Eq.3** and **Eq.4** from **Eq.1** and **Eq.2**.

But the result I derived is different from the paper, and I don't know where I am wrong. Taking **Eq.2** to derive **Eq.4** as an example, my derivation is as follows:
$$
\varepsilon _0\frac{d^2V}{dx^2}=n_0e\exp \left( \frac{eV}{kT} \right) \Rightarrow \varepsilon _0E^2=n_0kT\exp \left( \frac{eV}{kT} \right) 
$$
It is obvious that the left side of the equation is missing by 1/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you did the derivation but here are the steps
$$
\varepsilon _0\frac{d^2V}{dx^2}=n_0e\left[ \exp \left( \frac{eV}{kT} \right) -1 \right] \,\,\text{for}\,\,x<0
$$
we have
$$
\varepsilon _0\frac{d^2V}{dx^2} \frac{dV}{dx} = n_0e\left[ \exp \left( \frac{eV}{kT} \right) -1 \right]\dfrac{dV}{dx} 
$$
where we multiply $V'$ so we can integrate once
or
$$
\varepsilon _0\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}V'^2 = n_0e\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{kT}{e}\exp \left( \frac{eV}{kT} \right) - V\right]
$$
this leads to
$$
\varepsilon _0\frac{1}{2}V'^2  = n_0e\left[\frac{kT}{e}\exp \left( \frac{eV}{kT} \right) - V\right] + C
$$
where $C$ is the integration constant
we can re-write as
$$
\varepsilon _0\frac{1}{2}E^2 = n_0e\left[\frac{kT}{e}\exp \left( \frac{eV}{kT} \right) - V\right] + C
$$
using the boundary conditions $E =0, V=0$ this means
$$
0 = n_0e\left[\frac{kT}{e}\cdot 1  - 0\right] + C
$$
or
$$
C = -n_0e\frac{kT}{e}
$$
this leads to
$$
\varepsilon _0\frac{1}{2}E^2 = n_0e\left[\frac{kT}{e}\exp \left( \frac{eV}{kT} \right) - V\right] -n_0e\frac{kT}{e} = n_0e\left[\frac{kT}{e}\exp \left( \frac{eV}{kT} \right) - \frac{kT}{e} - V\right]
$$
we finally arrive at
$$
\varepsilon _0\frac{1}{2}E^2= n_0kT\left[\exp \left( \frac{eV}{kT} \right) - 1 - \frac{e}{kT}V\right]
$$
e.g. Eq. 3

Comment: Thank you very much, my derivation idea is different from yours, I'll check my problem again.

Comment: @Richardo. no worries - I think the key approach is the multiplication by $V'$ since the r.h.s does not involve any other other variables other than $V$ e.g. $V'' = f(V)$